# how to adjust the image size such that ImageAssemble works properly

Tags: image

When using `ImageAssemble` to combine several images, the size difference between them is a big problem. This problem contains the following parts

1. `ImageSize` option may not generate the exact size you want. As shown in the code, two images have the same setting with `ImageSize->22*22` but the actual dimensions of them are different. fig1 is {484,329} while fig2 is {484,323}.How to keep them in an exactly same size ?

   ```
   ClearAll[fig1, fig2];
   fig1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, ImageSize -> 22 22, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 2/3];
   fig2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], 2.1 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {-1.2, 1.2},ImageSize -> 22 22, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 2/3];
   ImageDimensions@fig1
   ImageDimensions@fig2
   ```
2. The margin of `Framelabel` and `FrameTicks` is also included in the calculation of `ImageSize`, which means two images with different `Framelabel` or `FrameTicks` may have different exact size even if their `ImageSize` is set to be the same. fig1 shows {484,338} while fig2 shows {323}. How to resize the images so that the exact size of image is not affect by the margin of frame ?

   ```
   ClearAll[fig1, fig2, tickX1, tickX2];
   tickX1 = Transpose[{Table[\[Pi]*i, {i, 0, 2}],Table[Style[ToString[i*2] <> "\[Pi]", 25], {i, 0, 2}]}];
   fig1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1},ImageSize -> 22 22, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 2/3,FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {tickX1, None}}]
   fig2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {-1.2, 1.2},ImageSize -> 22 22, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 2/3];
   ImageDimensions@fig1
   ImageDimensions@fig2
   ```

To sum up, I just want to combine several images using `ImageAssemble` or `ImageCollege`. Any solution that solve my problem is welcome. Thank you !

Comment: You mean `ConformImages`?

Comment: yes, the same kind of thing. The actual size of different images is a problem to me.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by yode:

```
{fig1C, fig2C} = ConformImages[{fig1, fig2}];
ImageAssemble[{fig1C, fig2C}]
```

or you can use

```
GraphicsRow[{fig1, fig2}]
```

(or related GraphicsGrid if you have many plots).